# Unable to access routes after build creation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i am unable to access routes after build creation and i am getting 404 page not found message.

i had created a react application and created build successfully after than i am unable to access the pages. when i try to access the pages i am getting error like 404 not found.

if i access manually like xyxz.com/#/xyz then it is working fine but if i try access from navbar and from any link i am getting 404 error.

Instead of BrowserRouter i am using HashRouter even though i am getting 404 error

For ref please see this website

https://cars.freecodelife.com/

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to add a new file named "_redirects" in your public folder.

in this new File write "/* /index.html 200"

then you have to add "&& echo '/* /index.html 200' | cat >build/_redirects " behind your build-script ...

so it looks like

"build": "react-scripts build && echo '/* /index.html 200' | cat >build/_redirects ",

hope that works

Regards